# Issue of invalid access token when trying to get households

Tags: sonos

I haven't had an issue getting access tokens, but when I try to test my access token by requesting households, I am getting 'Invalid Access Token' as a response. My refresh token appears to be working fine, but even refreshed access tokens are failing for this request.

I may be setting up my curl incorrectly for this request, can you please let me know exactly which tokens/keys/values are to be placed in these 2 headers, I don't find the documentation to be clear:

Authorization: ***** Hidden credentials *****
X-Sonos-Api-Key: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [sample getHouseholds request](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/discover/), you need to provide your access token as a header in the format:

```
Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>
```

and then your API Key (generated when you created your integration) in a second header:

```
X-Sonos-Api-Key: <Api-Key>
```

Be sure to also include the content-type header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue of invalid access token, but now the response I am getting is: 100RESTEASY003065: Can not consume content type

Comment: Try application/json as the content type instead. Documentation error, should be fixed now.